# Buildozer failed to execute the last command (android debug)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6, buildozer

```html
<pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py&quot;, line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    &quot;__main__&quot;, mod_spec)
  File &quot;/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py&quot;, line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File &quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py&quot;, line 1196, in &lt;module&gt;
    main()
  File &quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py&quot;, line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File &quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py&quot;, line 657, in __init__
    self.ctx.setup_dirs(self.storage_dir)
  File &quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py&quot;, line 169, in setup_dirs
    raise ValueError(&apos;storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please &apos;
ValueError: storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please specify a path with --storage-dir
<font color="#AA0000"># Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=&quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a&quot; --ndk-api=21</font>
<font color="#AA0000"># ENVIRONMENT:</font>
</pre>
```

That came out when I typed:

buildozer android debug

Here is the copy of the last lines of the terminal: [Terminal](https://ravenswoodsch-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/43546_rws_uk_net/ETyK2BhiE4FBgp51vjw4SN8B0ieB1HZgpI0l9hbSPHD3Tg?e=P5hVwc)

here is the entire folder of the app after I tried to debug/compile it: [GUI example](https://ravenswoodsch-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/43546_rws_uk_net/EtpAhgKsNmBCnlDH8OYAkyQBwG_U1s3Ol4sV9uxuX_vz6Q?e=kXV2nD)

Comment: `--storage-dir=&quot;/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI` <- what is that &quot doing there?

Comment: I actually don't know

Answer (score 1):

If your main.py file is in the path which contains spaces, then bulldozer is not going to work

So, remove all the spaces from folder name in which main.py lies

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution here: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1526

## Cause of error

The error due to which buildozer failed is `ValueError: storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please specify a path with --storage-dir`

Actually the path `/home/kivy/Desktop/GUI Example/` where your program is located contains spaces.

## Solution

Rename the folder `GUI Example` to `GUI_example` and try again!